# R: Performing a Calculation on a Vector

Tags: r

I think I have a pretty basic question for R but am having trouble finding an example. Say I have a vector of numbers

```
practice<-c(1,2,10,15,17,1,2,4)
```

and I want to calculate the change between numbers. The length of the vector is fixed at 36 observations. Example of what I want to calculate is ((2/1)-1),((10/2-1),.... I am thinking of building a for loop where I reference the position and have a counter associated with it.

Comment: Please take out the cursed loops out of your head. We don't use them in 99% of the time in R. Simply do `practice[-1L]/practice[-length(practice)] - 1L`

Comment: One question could you define what the -1L is. Would you define the L above this as the length of the vector or does it have a specific meaning in R?

Comment: `1L` is one long, i.e. 1 as a long integer.

Comment: It's just saying the the number before it is an integer. This is just SO nonsense when you are trying to look smart. You could just do `practice[-1]/practice[-length(practice)] - 1`

Comment: I was thinking that it meant 1 as an interger but never used the 1L before so I wanted to be clear on that. I am new to R so I am learning new things everyday.

Answer (score 5):

One of the benefits of using R is its [vectorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming), which means that it can easily perform operations on an entire vector at once rather than having to loop through each element.

As David Arenburg mentioned in a comment (with updates thanks to BondedDust and Dominic Comtois), you can in your case do this:

```
practice[-1] / head(practice, -1) - 1
```

What does this do?

`practice[-1]` references the entire vector except the first element.

```
> practice[-1]
[1] 2 10 15 17 1 2 4
```

Similarly, `head(practice, -1)` references the entire vector except the last element.

```
> head(practice, -1)
[1] 1 2 10 15 17 1 2
```

If we divide these, we get a vector consisting of each element in the original vector divided by the element that precedes it. We can divide these vectors directly because division is a vectorized operation.

```
> practice[-1] / head(practice, -1)
[1] 2.0000 5.0000 1.5000 1.1333 0.0588 2.0000 2.0000
> #    ^      ^      ^      ^      ^      ^      ^
> #   2/1   10/2   15/10  17/15   1/17   2/1    4/2
```

As you have in your example, we can subtract 1 at the end.

```
> practice[-1] / head(practice, -1) - 1
[1] 1.0000 4.0000 0.5000 0.1333 -0.9412 1.0000 1.0000
```

This is applied to each element in the vector since addition is also a vectorized operation in R.

No loops necessary!

The equivalent loop code would be this:

```
x <- NULL
for (i in 1:(length(practice) - 1)) {
    x[i] <- practice[i + 1] / practice[i] - 1
}
x
[1] 1.0000 4.0000 0.5000 0.1333 -0.9412 1.0000 1.0000
```

While that also gets you what you want, it's obviously a lot longer. In fact, in many cases equivalent loop code is significantly slower too, since loops carry around a lot of extra baggage at each iteration. So besides simplifying your code, vectorization will often help speed it up too.

Comment: `tail(practice, -1)` is more compact and expressive than `practice[-length(practice)]`

Comment: Actually `tail(practice, -1)` **equals** `practice[-1]`. I think you meant `head(practice, -1)`

Comment: @DominicComtois: Thanks, missed that. Added your update to the answer.